# .ajax - Appended success data being duplicated

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm getting some data with .ajax and then appending the data to the html element. Right now, there two audio posts and data that are being retrieved. But what's happening, the method in the code below is appending the post data from both posts to each of them. So say, Post A has the data from Post A and B. Post B, has the data from Post A and B. What am I missing in the code that's causing this?

```
$('.audio.post').each(function() {
    var audiopostID = $(this).attr('data-postID');

    $(this).find('.standard-player').hide();

    var audioPath = '/api/read/json?id=' + audiopostID;

    $.ajax({
        url: audioPath,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
            audioSrc = data.posts[0]['audio-player'];
            audioURL = decodeURIComponent(/audio_file=(.*)&color/.exec(audioSrc)[1]);
            //console.log(audioURL);

            $('.custom-player').append('<audio preload="none" controls>');
            $('audio').append($('<source>').attr({
                src: audioURL,
                type: 'audio/mpeg'
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

When viewing the elements in the console (http://cl.ly/O0pk), each post has two `<audio>` and the first `<audio>` tag having both `<source>` tags. My apologies for the squirrelly description here. Just trying to better understand the .ajax usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of the current audio if you don't want to give them an id:

```
$('.audio.post').each(function() {
    var audiopostID = $(this).attr('data-postID');
    var $thatAudio = $(this).closest('audio'); // Or however you can navigate to it

    $(this).find('.standard-player').hide();

    var audioPath = '/api/read/json?id=' + audiopostID;

    $.ajax({
        url: audioPath,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
            audioSrc = data.posts[0]['audio-player'];
            audioURL = decodeURIComponent(/audio_file=(.*)&color/.exec(audioSrc)[1]);
            //console.log(audioURL);

            $('.custom-player').append('<audio preload="none" controls>');
            $thatAudio.append($('<source>').attr({
                src: audioURL,
                type: 'audio/mpeg'
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In case you missed it - look at $thatAudio above and inside the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

`$('audio').append`

jQuery Translation: "I'm going to find *all* `audio` elements in the DOM and append this stuff to them.

Give your `audio` elements a unique ID to solve this problem.